# Finding version of GPy

Tags: python, python-module

I use the Python module GPy, and I want to find out what version I am using.

I saw that I can type:

```
pip freeze
```

which apparently lists all the installed packages, but GPy doesn't appear on that list for some reason. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

I've also tried dir(GPy) but I don't see anything like '**version**'

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it with pip ?
I suggest you to try

> pip show GPy

Otherwise use your distribution packet manager to retrieve this information.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't actually install it. It's just on a computer that I am using.